# Kotlin readBytes() never completes

Tags: android, sockets, stream, kotlin, bluetooth-socket

I am only trying to write and read across a Bluetooth Socket but i my readBytes call is not completing. I think that this is very simple but maybe i am just using the wrong type of stream or something. As of right now my code is just sending a small amount of text as bytes. This is placeholder code that will be replaced with code that writes and reads a file over the stream. Here is my Receive Thread:

```
class ReceiveThread(val inStream:BufferedInputStream):Thread() {

var bytes:ByteArray? = null


override fun run() {
    BluetoothService.log("Begin ${BTS_Constants.THREAD_RECEIVE}")
    BluetoothService.log("preparing to read data")
    name = BTS_Constants.THREAD_RECEIVE

//here is my new code
    inStream.use {
        do{
            count++
            BluetoothService.log("read loop round $count")
            byteList.add(it.read() as Byte)
        }while (it.available()>0)
     }
    BluetoothService.log("data read: ${byteList.get(0) as Char}")
}
}
```

and here is my Send Thread:

```
class SendThread(val outStream:BufferedOutputStream, val file:File? = null):Thread(){

var bytes:ByteArray? = null

override fun run() {
    BluetoothService.log("Begin : ${BTS_Constants.THREAD_SEND}")
    name = BTS_Constants.THREAD_SEND

    bytes = "hello testing".toByteArray()
    try{
        outStream.use {
            it.write(bytes)
            it.flush()
        }
    }catch (ioe:IOException){

    }

    BluetoothService.log("data sent")
}

}
```

the data is successfully sent, and the `BluetoothService.log("data sent")` call is reached and displayed in the logcat for the device that is running a Send Thread. For the device running the Receive Thread logs the "Preparing to read data" message, but never logs the `data read: "$bytes message"`.

How can i make this call to inStream.readBytes() complete?

Edit: new Error message that i am receiving:

```
11-27 23:45:29.298 16253-16413/com.example.zemcd.fileblue E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RECEIVE
                                                                        Process: com.example.zemcd.fileblue, PID: 16253
                                                                        java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
                  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:588)
                  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:96)
                  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
                  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
                  at com.example.zemcd.fileblue.ReceiveThread.run(BluetoothService.kt:230)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look on source of Kotlin extension function [`readBytes`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.60/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/io/IOStreams.kt#L115) you see that it starts loop while `InputStream.read(buffer) > 0`. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])):

> This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

Second iteration of this loop freeze your program.
So don't use method  `readBytes`. Just `read(buffer)`.
For example - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection

Update:

Now  `ReceiveThread` can receive one message from stream. But your bluetooth socket is close. So your problem is in setup bluetooth connection and `inStream`'s initialization. Maybe you have wrong send part too.

Comment: thanks. this answer is very infomative, but i made the changes to the code and it is still blockiing. maybe i am misunderstanding. I changed `bytes = it.readBytes()` to `byteSize = it.read(buffer)` and added a byteSize variable to my code. as an Int field of my Receive Thread. am i needing to do something more? i am not seeing any more in the documentation and because i am using kotlin i can't do the`while((byteSize = it.read(buffer))!=-1)` loop.

Comment: @Mox_z Are you sure that ReceiveThread call method read before  SendThread call method write ?

Comment: Yes, the write side is completing the send. but could this have something to do with it being a BufferedInputStream? is there a different technique used there?

Comment: see above comment

Comment: @Mox_z why you can't use `while`? And can it be a bluetooth connect problem?

Comment: i guess in kotlin the example that i showed you is an assignment and cannot be used in place of the expression that while(expression) expects as an argument. maybe there is a work around? i will try taking a look at my send code. maybe im just missing something there. also, i am going to post an edit to this question showing the updated code and new error message i am receiving. I think this is helping to clarifiy my problem.

Comment: i posted an edit. maybe you were right about the problem being with my send code and not my receive code?

Comment: @Mox_z I've updated my answer. You have a close bt socket on receive side so you don't have bluetooth connection between programs on your devices. Therefore you can't read any of bytes and have an exception.

Comment: could this be something to do with me not correctly synchronizing my threads? my outStream and inStream references are passed in as args but the streams originally come from a BluetoothSocket aquired by a singleton object: BluetoothService. could passing the socket into an unsynchronized thread be part of the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160046/discussion-between-mox-z-and-dmitrii-nechepurenko).